# VueJS2: Declariing strict mode prevents me from accessing object in console

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I am using VueJS and writing my JavaScript in strict mode (function form). The problem is that I can no longer access my Vue instance in Chrome devtools. If I modified my code to not run in strict mode, I can easily access my Vue object.

Does anyone know why this happens?

> Here's my code:

```
(function () {

    'use strict';

    var app = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
            selectedProducts: [],
            ...snip...
    });

}());
```

So, then in my view, **I select a radio button** and then in the Chrome devTools console, I type the following:

```
app.selectedProducts
```

I get `undefined` in console. If I also type `app.selectedProducts.length`, I get the following error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property "length" of undefined at <anonymous>:1:21`

But, simply removing the use strict mode syntax from the JS makes everything work fine and I can access the objects in console.

Does 'use strict' mode do anything special to my object that I can't access them in console?

Comment: You'll have to provide more details on how you set up your Vue instance. Can you put it in a jsfiddle so people can have a deeper look? Or tell us more about whether you set up your project using webpack or on Node or any other presets?

Comment: Perhaps you should get the VueJS dev tools from the Chrome store. It enables testing of your VueJS app without the need to disable strict mode.

Comment: When you say, "strict mode (function form)" do you mean you are defining your Vue inside an IIFE? Can you provide the code?

Comment: Just added more info

Comment: where do you call `app.selectedProducts` ? is it inside the self invoking function i.e : `(function(){ ... }());` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using the syntax you're using (and generally when using for example functions), you're changing the scope in which your `app` variable gets declared and can be accessed.

Inner scopes can (usually) access variables from outer scopes, but not the other way round.

```
// window scope that can't access variables from nested scope
(function () {
    // nested scope that can access variables from outer scope
    'use strict';

    var app = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
            selectedProducts: [],
            ...snip...
    });

}());
```

The outmost scope is the `window` scope, and variables declared here will be attached to the `window` object, which is also what dev tools uses (if you're using `app` there, you're really using `window.app`).

To use the variable now declared inside your `strict` scope in dev tools, declare it in the `window` scope instead, and then initialise it with your Vue instance in the `strict` scope:

```
var app;

(function () {
    'use strict';

    app = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
            selectedProducts: [],
            ...snip...
    });

}());
```

Comment: That makes sense. thanks! Now I am getting linter errors for things like:  `"Vue" is not defined.`. But, you started me on the right path, thanks for your time.

Comment: The 'is defined but never used' is usually if you don't use a variable after declaring it - that's why you usually don't save your Vue instance to a variable (since you won't be using it anymore) - just remember to remove the variable once you're done debugging

Comment: 'Vue is not defined' is probably due to imports not resolving correctly - check how you're importing vue and if that's all correct.

Answer (score 0):

If you declare the app variable inside the self invoking function, the variable will not be accessible to the global scope. Just to remember, in javascript scope changes inside **function**. 
You can use the `window` variable to define global variable

```
(function (window) {

   'use strict';

   window.app = new Vue({
       el: '#app',
       data: {
           selectedProducts: [],
           ...snip...
   });

}(window));
```